# Contact Form 7 Validation

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a Contact Form with demo_mode on. The form has a submit button, which is assigned the following additional settings

```
on_submit: "window.open("https://www.google.com","_self");"
```

Once the submit button is clicked, the page goes to Google. I can see form validation is performed since there are warning lines under invalid fields, but it still goes to Google.

Could anybody tell me how to stop invalid form submission? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using the [`on_sent_ok` hook](http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/) instead:

```
on_sent_ok: "window.open('https://www.google.com', '_self');"
```

This will only fire when the form has been submitted without errors, and an email has been sent.

Also, be careful of your use of double-quotes everywhere.